Service worker not triggering visible notification
I am testing a new integration with push notifications, and I get the correct console.logs, but in the end, there is no browser notification showing up.
This is my service worker:
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("Service Worker installing");
  // Skip waiting to immediately activate the service worker
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("Service Worker activated");
});
self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
  console.log("here");
  if (event.data) {
    console.log("Push event!! ", JSON.parse(event.data.text()));
    showLocalNotification(
      "Notification ",
      JSON.parse(event.data.text()),
      self.registration
    );
  } else {
    console.log("Push event but no data");
  }
});

const showLocalNotification = (title, data, swRegistration) => {
  console.log("server contacted me for notification");
  swRegistration.showNotification(title, data);
};


I have vapid keys, I use NodeJS with express, and the REST POST endpoint is correctly subscribing to, storing and retrieving a subscription for use, and sending it to the client. So I am correctly installing, activating but not actually displaying, the notification. It logs "server contacted me for notification"

For those that are as dumb as me, I actually TODAY turned off notifications for Chrome. Nevermind, everything is working.
